# ImageView SetImage NullPointer Exception

Tags: javafx, imageview

So I have this code in JavaFX:

```
Image img = new Image("http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/javafx/images/javafx-documentation.png");
imgView_movie.setImage(img)
```

Here's my fxml code, I added a default image value for it:

```xml
<ImageView fx:id="imgView_movie" fitHeight="335.0" fitWidth="335.0" onMouseClicked="#goToUrl" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true" styleClass="" GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="1">
    <image>
        <Image url="@broken.jpg" />
    </image>
</ImageView>
```

I don't know if there's anything wrong but I keep getting this error:

```
javafx.fxml.LoadException:/C:/Users/crsst/IdeaProjects/PersonalMovieDb/out/production/PersonalMovieDb/sample/mainpage.fxml:16

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2579)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at sample.Login.submit(Login.java:37)
at sample.Login.onClickSubmit(Login.java:53)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at sample.Home.<init>(Home.java:67)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442)
at sun.reflect.misc.ReflectUtil.newInstance(ReflectUtil.java:51)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:927)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$InstanceDeclarationElement.processAttribute(FXMLLoader.java:971)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:220)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:744)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processStartElement(FXMLLoader.java:2707)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2527)
... 67 more`
```

any help would be very much appreciated im losing my mind here

Comment: Your question doesn't have enough data for us to provide a resolution. Please provide the complete stacktrace and the line of code where the exception has occurred.

Comment: Are you sure that "broken.jpg" is stored in "C:/Users/crsst/IdeaProjects/PersonalMovieDb/out/production/PersonalMovieDb/sample/"?

Answer (score 4):

The controller hasn't yet initialized the fxml components ,so **when you add the Image the ImageView is still null**.([javafx.fxml.LoadException](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/fxml/LoadException.html))

> First way

So one way is to change it programmatically after the controller had been initialized ... like this:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable{

  @FXML
  private ImageView imageView;

  @Override
  public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

     imageView.setImage("path here");
  }

}
```

So now when the **FXMLLoader** has initalized the components of fxml file 
the method initialize is called.

> Second Way

On **[SceneBuilder](http://gluonhq.com/open-source/scene-builder/)**(recommended) check(**use fx:root construct**) and don't use a default controller so you can use your class multiple times(as a costume item):

```
public class Editor extends BorderPane{

@FXML
private Button save;

// Constructor
public Editor() {

    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("fxml file"));
    loader.setRoot(this);
    loader.setController(this);

    try {
        loader.load();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    save.setText("save");
 }


 }
```

As you see here you can call this class which is a costume BorderPane with a Button inside it.

In the constructor i can modify the button save directly.

Answer (score 1):

ImgView_movie = New imgview will save you my friend.  It isnt initialised so you can not set an attribute of this object yet

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention it's already initialized on the fxml file, i just wanted to change it programmatically

Comment: It's null so I think the controller hasnt initialised the view elements yet.  Show  your controller class in code and the method that s calling the nullpointer so we can help more accurate